# External dll packing with NPAPI Plugin extension

Tags: plugins, dll, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, npapi

I created an NPAPI plugin. It uses two other Dlls.
I need to pack those Dll files along with Plugin dll as Extension.
How can I do that? So that I can Place that dll to any folder and register it.

Is there any way to do this?

Sorry if its a duplicate.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pack it as an extension, you just put the two DLLs you need in the same directory in the extension as the plugin DLL.

Note that some browsers the search path may have difficulties finding those DLLs; if you find this to be the case you could try DELAYLOAD linking those DLLs and use [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add the plugin dll directory to the path.